# Unity - Using button for touch control

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on my 2D Android project in Unity 4.5 and I want to use Button objects for touch control so I made this:

GameObject - Button "Left" - OnClick() = player | Control.Steer | 1

GameObject - Button "Right"- OnClick() = player | Control.Steer | 0
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLSPn.png "example"
![example][1]

and script

```
public void Steer(int updown){
        if (updown == 0){
            transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0,0,rotationSpeed) *-1);
        }
        if (updown == 1){
            transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0,0,rotationSpeed));
        }
    }
```

but the probles is that is working like I click button and it's rotate just once. I want it to behave like while is button pressed it will repeating the code. Can I somehow do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnClick is an event and is called when a click event occurs. If you wan't your object to rotate while the mouse is pressed and over a gameobject use: 1. Input.mouseButtonDown and check if the mouse is over your object 
2. OnMouseDown() in a script attached to your object (this will automatically check if the mouse is over your object)
3. for the new UI elements use the EventSystem and check if your button is or not currently selected

points 1,2 require your object to have a Collider attached